# Mapping the interval [0,1] to [-1,1] with side conditions

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

I'm wondering if there is a differentiable function that takes $\lambda$ as parameter
$$f_\lambda : [0,1] \rightarrow [-1,1], x \mapsto f(x)$$
which is monotonic growing and has the side conditions
$$f_\lambda(\lambda) = 0 \wedge f_\lambda(0) = -1 \wedge f_\lambda(1)=1$$
where $\lambda \in I$ with $I \subseteq (0,1) \setminus{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I tried to find functions of the form
$$ f_\lambda(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$
and
$$ f_\lambda(x) = a\cdot\log(bx + c) +d $$
but could not come up with a solution for either of those.

Any ideas?

### Edit:

The solution proposed by @A.J.
$$ f_\lambda(x) =  2 \cdot x^{\tfrac{\ln(1/2)}{\ln(\lambda)}} - 1$$
is a solution for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$

Comment: edited the question to clarify what I'm asking

Comment: I do not understand why you introduce $\lambda$ ? Is there something missing in your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to find any non-linear increasing function that maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$, then subtract $1$; e.g. $\;2x^n-1 \;(n\neq0),\; 3^x-2,\; 2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)-1,\;$ etc.

Comment: the function $2x^a -1$ where $a = \frac{\log(1/2)}{\log(\lambda)} $ seems to be the solution I was looking for.

Comment: +1 both for A.J. for their partial solution, and for @Ackdari for turning this partial solution into a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

$f:[0,1]\rightarrow [a,b] : x\mapsto (1-x)a + xb$.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. The range is fixed in the question and OP wants a function which is $0$ at some point other than $\frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(x)\ :=\ \left(\frac x{1-\lambda}+\frac{1-x}\lambda\right)\cdot(x-\lambda) $$

This function is increasing in $\ [0;1]\ $only when $\ \lambda\ $ belongs to an interval neighborhood of $\ \frac 12,\ $ but not outside that neighborhood. Thus this is only a partial solution.

Comment: One might want to add that in general, $n$ points always lie on the graph of a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ (if they lie on the graph of a function at all).

Comment: Yes, Lagrange :)